# Helper url Laravel con parámetros cambia mis directorios

Tags: php, laravel

HREF=“{url(url)}” detecta bien mis archivos en public por ejemplo si mis estilos están en assets el detecta estos estilos pero si le pongo la url con el parámetros me saca un directorio atrás HREF=“{url(url/1)}” como puedo redireccionar sin que suceda esto

Comment: para css y js tienes que usar la función de asset()

Comment: Muchas gracias muy útil :)

Answer (score 1):

Los recursos, ficheros CSS, JS, imágenes, etc., es decir el contenido de la carpeta "public" se cargan con el helper: `asset()`, p.e.:

```
<link href="{{ asset('fonts/nunito/nunito.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

donde el directorio "fonts", estaría directamente dentro de la capeta "public".

Se generá el siguiente HTML:

```
<link href="http://www.midominio.com/fonts/nunito/nunito.css" rel="stylesheet" >
```

El helper `url()` se usa para URLs de la aplicación, principalmente, dentro de enlaces, p.e.:

```
<a href="{{ url('proyectos') }}" title="Página de proyectos">
    Proyectos
</a>
```

Esto generá el siguiente HTML:

```
<a href="https://www.midominio.com/proyectos" title="Página de proyectos">
    Proyectos
</a>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias fue muy útil tu respuesta.